# Can't display my rows from my data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have two data extensions, books & subscribers

[image]

[image]

I am trying to extract the list of books as well as the name of the user assigned to each book via the id ( subscriber id )

This is my code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Book name</th>
        <th>Book price</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>

%%[

var @bookQueries
set @bookQueries = LookupRows("TaouBenTestBooks","return","1")

If RowCount(@bookQueries) > 0 Then
For @i = 1 to RowCount(@bookQueries) do
SET @bookQuery = ROW(@bookQueries, @i)
SET @subscriberId = FIELD(@bookQuery, 'subscriberId')
SET @bookName = FIELD(@bookQuery, 'bookName')
SET @bookPrice = FIELD(@bookQuery, 'bookPrice')

If IsNull(@subscriberId) Then

SET @firstname = LOOKUP("TaouBenTestSubscribers", "firstname", "id", @subscriberId)
SET @lastname = LOOKUP("TaouBenTestSubscribers", "lastname", "id", @subscriberId)
SET @fullname = Concat(@firstname, " ", @lastname)
]%%


    <tr>
        <td>%%=v(@bookName)=%%</td>
        <td>%%=v(@bookPrice)=%%</td>
        <td>%%=v(@fullname)=%%</td>
    </tr>
%%[

ENDIF

Next @i

Else
]%% <tr><td>ERROR MAYBE ?</td></tr>%%[
endif

]%%

</table>
```

What I get is just empty table, I don't neither the data neither the info, and I don't get any errors as well, just the table header

What is wrong in your opinions ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the usage of the [IsNull](https://ampscript.guide/isnull/) function in the IF statement within FOR loop.

You might have confused the logic to check `@subscriberId`. You need to check if the `@subscriberId` **is not empty**, then proceed further and do some Lookups to set the variables which are used later on in the table.

In the code, you have the opposite logic - if `@subscriberId` **is null**, then do some Lookups but `@subscriberId` is not null, thus no Lookups are performed and leads to the empty table.

To fix it, simply change `If IsNull(@subscriberId) Then` --> `If NOT EMPTY(@subscriberId) Then`

**upd:** You do not get a text from the ELSE part because `RowCount(@bookQueries) > 0` is true, you do have some records coming from LookupRows. However, your `If IsNull(@subscriberId) Then` statement is wrapping Lookups + output of Lookups + output of fields from LookupRows. In other words, you are checking when `@subscriberId` is null and since it is not null, all content below up to the ENDIF (the one before `Next @i`)is hidden.

Comment: But if this is the case, then I must get the html writting in the ELSE case, but I don't

Comment: That is the case since I have already tested it. Please read my updated answer.